# Will volatile variables in a class be set to 0 by default?

Tags: java

I know java will have a default constructor to initialize variables to 0, but how about volatile variables?

```
   class Test { 
       volatile long a;
       volatile double b;
       volatile int c;
    }
```

and I print them and every time result is 0, but is it guaranteed ?

Comment: `volatile` is irrelevant to the default value you will get for a variable; so yes - it is guaranteed.

Comment: (And `volatile` can't be used on those kinds of variable that don't allow default initialization ...)

Comment: To be precise, no constructor is involved with a primitive value in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java Language Specifiction, [section 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), says:

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created:
>
> - For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (byte)0.
> - For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (short)0.
> - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
> - For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
> - For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
> - For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
> - For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'.
> - For type boolean, the default value is false.
> - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

As you can see, this rule applies to all fields, regardless of their volatility.